# Unity: Efficient way to get the average pixel color for a portion of the camera viewport

Tags: unity, shaders, fragment-shader

At it's core, the problem I'm trying to solve is this:
I have a camera (not main) that I would like to project to a 2 pixel `RenderTexture`. I would like the first pixel to be the average color of all pixels in the left portion of the camera viewport (or a close approximation). And the second pixel to be the average color of all pixels in the right portion of the camera viewport.

So far I've looked into doing this via `OnRenderImage(src, dest)` but I'm open to any suggestions. Same goes with camera resolutions, 256x256 seems like a good starting point but open to suggestions here too. It's worth mentioning that I just threw together a brute-force non threaded approach that works but totally tanks FPS (nothing surprising)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This doesn't seem like an incredibly weird downscaling approach but I can't seem to find anything regarding it. There might be a clever way of dealing with this via a shader but I have yet to find it. Bilinear downscaling (which I think is what unity uses by default) sadly does not give the appropriate result.

*System compatibility is not an issue, Win 10, DX 12.*

Comment: This is normally done by downsampling frame buffer to a smaller render target, then downsampling that to an even smaller target, repeatedly in a chain until you're down to a two-pixel texture: one pixel for the left half, one for the right.

Comment: Thanks!! I've been doing this in a bit of a lazy fashion. The default scaling option in unity seems to be bilinear downscaling when you reduce by a factor of 2 (but gets loopy for any larger downscale). So I've been looping a `Graphics.Blit(src,dst)` until I get the desired size. This doesn't exactly start from the frame buffer though. And is still pretty costly. Anyone know what the most optimized way of doing this would be? I would love pointers on how to do this in a shader for instance.

Comment: Couldn’t you make the camera’s resolution 2x1 pixels? Maybe unity has some minimum...